# Bézout ring that is not a domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

A ring is Bézout if every finitely generated ideal is principal.

> **Question.** Any example of a Bézout ring which is not an integral domain ?

Comment: A non-integral domain quotient of a Bézout domain.

Comment: It's hard *not* to come up with examples. Like $F_2\times F_2$. What did you try, even?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Examples which aren't principal ideal rings:

- $\prod_{i\in I} F_i$ for any fields $F_i$ and infinite index set $I$.
- $R\times R$ where $R$ is any Bezout domain, or even $\prod_{i=1}^nR_i$ where each $R_i$ is a Bezout domain (at least one nonprincipal, if you want the product to be nonprincipal.)

Principal ideal rings that aren't domains:

- $\mathbb Z/(n)$, $n>1$ and not prime.
- $\mathbb F[x]/(p(x))$ for any nonprime polynomial $p(x)$.

Comment: [DaRT query](http://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/commsearch/commresults/?has=44&lacks=5)

Comment: Interesting site!